# Facing issues while migrating Android project with NDK version from r10e to latest version(r23b)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, migration, ndk-build

We have one android project with ndkbuild. We are using NDK version r10e and want to migrate it to latest version(r23b).
But we are facing lot of build issues while migrating and below is the main error.

error: use of undeclared identifier 'catopen
error: use of undeclared identifier 'catgets'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'cat close'

We resolved it by increasing minsdkversion from 21 to 26. Then the build got successful but app is crashing on launch.
Below is the log:
**A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 15954**

Please respond if anyone has faced this issue and resolved it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes many times.. It didn't work

Comment: _" the build got successful but app is crashing on launch"_. You'll have to analyze the stacktrace from the crash.